# Earliest numeric value for helium D3 line

Tags: physics, astronomy, experimental-physics, astrophysics

In late 1868, Norman Lockyer discovered the existence of the D3 emission line of helium in the solar spectrum. What was the earliest published example of a numeric value for the wavelength of this line, and what was the value?

By 1895, when Ramsay isolated helium, the line was sufficiently well-known that Lockyer could refer to it as "the 587.59 line", but I want to know how soon after its discovery the numeric value was established.

Comment: Have you consulted the original paper of Norman Lockyer? What does he say?

Comment: Janssen diiscovered the line already earlier that year. D1 and D2 were already known. Lockyer proposed it was another element than the one giving rise to D1 and D2.

Comment: Did they measure those wavelengths? This is perhaps what the OP needs to find from original works.

Comment: @M.Farooq From what I understand of it, these two wavelengths were known. Im not sure to what prcesion. So you would expect the frequency of this third line was known too.

Comment: @M.Farooq - Yes, the Royal Society paper. He does not mention wavelength.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder - I can't find Janssen's paper. Narratives about his discovery suggest that he did produce a numeric wavelength, but not what value he set. He seems to have realized that the line was not the right wavelength to be sodium, but I can't find out what he thought it was. Lockyer's number would be more pertinent, since was very close to the recovered helium wavelength - but I can't find that, either. I'm especially interested in the FIRST published value.

Comment: How could Lockyer know it was the 587.59 line? Did he measure this value?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder - That is essentially what I'm asking. He (or somebody) apparently did measure it. When did he (or anybody) publish the result?

Answer (score 2):

The earliest references that I can find about the measurement of helium D3 line is

**D'Arrest, H. L. (1872).** *Über die Position der Lichtlinie D3 im Protuberanzspectrum*. Astronomische Nachrichten, 79, 1. (On the position of D3 line in the prominence spectrum). For serious academic work, the 2 paged article need to be fully translated. You also need to see "Schellen's Spectralanalysis, 1871 p.380," cited there. DeepL is a very good translator, but you might need a lot of text pre-processing to get a decent translation. The machine translation methodology has been published in Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling.

[image]

> For the wavelength of the light in which $D_{3}$ appears, quite a lot of observations are available, in that the observers have always related the position itself consequently to the near sodium lines visible at the same time as $\boldsymbol{D}_{\mathbf{3}}$. If it is now assumed that
> $$
> \begin{array}{l}
> D_{1}=589,50 \text { angstr. }=1002,8  \mathrm{Kirchh} \\
> D_{2}=588,90 \quad=\quad=1006,8 \quad=
> \end{array}
> $$
> we get from Young's, Rayet's and other data
> $$
> D_{3}=587,50 \text { Angstr. }=1016,1 \text { Kirchh }
> $$

*Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)*

Sadly he does not cite Young's paper but there is a footnote

*) Rayet has e.g. $1016,8 \boldsymbol{K}$ which leads to $587,4 \boldsymbol{A} .$. If, on the other hand, in Schellen's Spectralanalysis, 1871 p.380, $D_{3}=588,27$ is set, this large deviation comes from the fact that all three $\boldsymbol{D}$ - lines appear at the place obviously about 0,93 too large.

In older times it appears that people were often unaware of previous works so measurements appear again.

**Maunder, E. W. (1889).** Spectroscopic observations of sundry stars and comets made at the Royal Observatory, Greenwich, chiefly in the years 1887 and 1888. *Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society*, 49, 300.

This seems to be the first because this paper does not give any reference to previous works.

[image]